# Of elderly “noun” omitted?

Tags: ellipsis, grammaticality-in-context

Source: National Geographic Magazine

> China is on the brink of a huge demographic shift. Over the next two decades, an unprecedented baby boom from the 1960s will age into “the largest number of **elderly** ever in the history of China,” says Yu Xie, a Princeton University sociologist who studies the country.

Why is elderly, adjective, not followed by a noun.

Is it a kind of ellipsis? Because the omitted word is assumed to be “people”.

Comment: It's just an "adjective serving as noun" usage, where the noun that the adjective would normally be modifying (***people***, for example, in your context) is implied but not explicitly stated . Same as *The **poor** are always with us, The **rich** are different,* etc. Your *specific* example is a bit less common (in most contexts we wouldn't have any other words between ***the*** and the "nounified adjective") - I personally would say it's therefore slightly "stylised", and should generally be avoided.

Comment: @James K: If the mods decide my comment is superfluous they will delete it. I don't want to spend the time creating a *full* answer myself, but I think the existing one is misleading in that it makes great play of the fact that this *particular* adjective happens to have dictionary definitions for its use as a noun. I'm not going to bother looking, but I expect *[the] **sick / wounded*** would also be thus defined, but this has little bearing on the fact that I can say *The wounded stayed behind while the **healthy** marched on*. And you won't find *that* noun usage in a dictionary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - One of the comments here was superfluous. It wasn't yours.

Comment: Compare *The number of sick and wounded treated there during the entire month of December was 178...*  or *We're running out of paint. We need to order five more cartons of high-gloss and five more cartons of matte.*   Collective noun formed from an attribute.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I find that a useful example, in that it reminds me that *lots* of adjectives can easily be pressed into service as nouns *provided the relevant "underlying" noun has already been explicitly mentioned*, as in *We have two kinds [of X] - this one's [adj1] and that one's [adj2]. Which do you want? - I'll have [the] adj1/2 [one] please*. But although some *adj1/2* values work fine without either of ***the*** or ***one*** there, some adjectives seem to require at least an article *(**the/a**)*, and others *also* require an explicit noun *(**one**)*. IDK if there's a pattern there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And I don't think it will always require explicit mention, if the term is used in a particular setting on a regular basis.  *Joe, can you order some more of the triple-thicks?*  That's just a dreamed-up example where in some shop, somewhere, some regularly sold item is available in a triple-ply version.  That fact that it's in the plural shows that it's not a case of ellipsis.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: That's another highly-relevant point about *the plural shows that it's not a case of ellipsis* (which I *also* hadn't consciously thought of until you pointed it out). I'm pretty sure there are some contexts / values for *[adjective]* that can work as both singular (implying ellipsis) and plural (implying nounification). Maybe you should write a *huge* answer covering all this stuff! :)

Answer (score 2):

The word *elderly* has a less-common (but still in wide use) noun form in addition to an adjective form. It is most commonly used in the singular form preceded by a 'the' to refer to a collective group of elderly people.

At [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elderly) it is defined as:

> (used with a plural verb) elderly people collectively; senior citizens (usually preceded by the)

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elderly) defines it as:

> an elderly person
>   with the additional note that the plural of 'elderly' in this form is also 'elderly'.